# Recursive bower install

Tags: bower

I've got a project which depends on another project which and both use Bower. I'd like `bower install` to also run on that component when I run it on the parent project. So far I haven't found anything in the [configuration spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.motxgepy7e9s), the man page or the online docs which hint at this, so I've simply navigated to the child project directory and ran `bower install` a second time. With a lot of dependencies, this wouldn't be feasible, so having `bower install -R` would be nice.

Comment: Why not add this to the [Bower Issues Page](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to do it using the 'bower' command in the terminal.
However I could successfully use [grunt auto_install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-auto-install) for this purpose.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    "auto_install": {
        options: {
            recursive: true,
            exclude: [
                ".git",
                "node_modules",
                "components",
                "grunt-tasks",
                ".sass-cache"
            ]
        }
    }
}};
```